# induction motor stability

Tags: induction-motor, stability

Does the change in slip (s) have any impact on load torque in an induction machine/motor? I know it affects the motoring torque. But do the load torque also get affected by the slightest measures if not more?

[image: with reference to fig 6.28(b). The article reads as - if the starting torque OA is higher than load torque, the rotor will accelerate till operating point C].
Now my question is if the load torque is independent of slip, shouldn't be BC (the graph for load torque) a straight line parallel to y axis rather than increasing slightly as slip tends to 0?

Comment: As slip increases, torque increases.  Slip is where the torque comes from.  No slip = no torque.

Comment: The load torque is by definition independent from slip, because that's a property of the driving machine. It may be dependent from speed, however, and this makes it dependent from the driving machine slip.

Comment: So ask a new question.  By changing or adding to the question, you make a moving target.  Hard to be concise when the question changes.  Frustrates the people who would answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slip is a function of torque. More torque on the shaft and there's more slip: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312616/torque-slip-characteristic-stability-analysis-for-induction-motor).

> Does the change in slip (s) has any impact on load torque in an
>   induction machine/motor ?

Re-arrange your thoughts - torque produces slip, not the other way round, Cause = torque; effect = slip.

Comment: I admit it is not the other way round.. However I have edited my question and posted the pic which led me to think so- how can BC the load torque characteristic not be a straight line as it should be otherwise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't edit your question because it potentially makes my answer look wrong or stupid. If you want help, be very clear in how you present the edits to your question and don't assume that anyone will naturally check previous history to see that I answered an earlier incarnation of your words.

Comment: Will take care of it in future. Being new to the platform wasn't aware of the functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to rearrange your thoughts: the load is only attached to the motor shaft.  It is happily* oblivious to the motor torque.  The load torque can only be a function of the shaft rotation of the motor.  So the load torque is *only* affected by shaft speed, acceleration, possibly jerk, and possibly shaft position (most likely the position of something that's geared down off of the shaft).

For a load that has a constant torque, or a torque that rises with increasing speed (which is not universal, but which accounts for practically all practical applications), the system will be stable.

* Well, happy to the extent that any insensate mechanical assembly can be.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to understand if you call the motor torque vs. speed curve its torque vs. speed **capability** curve. The load curve is then the load **demand** or **characteristic** curve. There is only one operating torque. It is the intersection of the motor capability curve and the load demand curve. The motor's demand curve shows the torque required to drive the load at any given speed. It is a characteristic of the load and is not influenced by the motor. The motor only determines where on the curve the operating point is.

The curves TL1 and TL2 posted in the question show loads that require increasing torque as speed increases. Curves of that shape are characteristic of fans and centrifugal pumps. In this case, they are more characteristic of centrifugal pumps because the torque at zero speed is significantly above zero. Fans tend to require practically no torque for very slow operation. A pump can be working against a standing column of water that will turn the motor backwards unless significant torque is applied.

If the load curves shown belong to the same pump and installation, the increase from TL1 to TL2 would represent an increase in back pressure due to something like pumping water into the bottom of a reservoir that has a rising water level. The motor has changed nothing except to slow down experiencing more slip and generating more torque in order to operate the a different torque-speed operating point.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I understood the concept. Can you please elaborate qualitatively why pumps/fans and other such loads require increasing torques as speed increases.

Comment: I interpreted the revision of your question as an attempt to clarify the original question while others interpreted that as an expansion or redirection of the question. Now I see the above comment as a completely new question. The principles that lead to increasing torque demand with speed are the turbo machinery affinity laws. While everyone involved with electric motors driving pumps needs to be aware of them, their derrivation is a mechanical engineering concept.