# Induction motor: T-Slip Characteristics look weird

Tags: induction-motor, device-characteristics

I was recently doing a first-course lab on Induction Motors.
We were asked to plot the torque-slip characteristics of a 4-pole 3 phase induction motor (3.7kW).

I just analyzed the data I plotted from the wattmeter readings (connected as shown below) and the rpm measured using a tachometer.

[image: part of ckt diagram showing wattmeter connection: voltage coil across A of IM and 3-ph N, current coil sees current entering A of IM]

Here's the T-slip data I plotted on my spreadsheet.

[image: t-slip from my lab]

Data points were obtained by gradually loading a mechanically coupled DC generator.

I don't think my plot looks anything like the t-slip diagrams from my lectures and even Google Images.

Can someone who knows what's going on explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can someone who knows what's going on explain it to me?*

It looks pretty normal to me; as you increase torque the motor slips a little more. Maybe the graphical representations you have previously seen look different but are reflected in your diagram. For instance, here's one that looks pretty similar: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-explain-the-torque-slip-characteristics-of-both-AC-single-phase-and-3-phase-induction-motor).

And your graph appears to be coinciding with "the stable region". But, if you looked at this graph that shows torque against speed you might get confused: -

[image]

Taken from a [stack exchange question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312616/torque-slip-characteristic-stability-analysis-for-induction-motor).

In this graph the right hand side of the characteristic is where you graph begins because it shows speed and not slip on the x-axis.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Also, keep practicing guitar and piano - you never stop practicing!

Comment: Ah, yes, I will!

Comment: BTW I just heard some of your tracks. I liked "So you wanna be a soldier" very much.

Comment: Ah, maybe you also like Pink Floyd. I won a competition with that song!